# Unable to retrieve data in string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

```
self.pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iPhone_SDK_License" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];
NSString *htmlstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It is showing nil in htmlstr, so need some assistance on it.

Comment: You need to debug this more. Is pdfPath nil? Is htmlData nil?

Answer (score 0):

A pdf is not an html file so I assume that initWithData:encoding: just cannot understand the data and so fails.

Use [stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:) to see the details of the error.

Comment: It is again showing garbage value so please find my code as below

code 
self.pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iPhone_SDK_License" ofType:@"pdf"];
 self.pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];
 [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfUrl]];

NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:pdfUrl];
 [fliteEngine speakText:myString];
 NSLog(@"myString %@", myString);

Comment: What encoding I should is used for pdf encoding as it is showing an error

Comment: pdf os a defined format including indicies not just text so a simple read and encoding will not work http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format

Comment: @Umaid: PDF is a binary format.  Some of it is text, some of it is images, some of it is compressed data. You have absolutely no hope of just converting a PDF into a text string.